# Returning a file to View and Download in .Net Core MVC 2.2

Tags: c#, download, asp.net-core-mvc, http-headers

In my controller, I want the user to view an image (could be jpg,giff,png,tiff) within the browser and also have the option to download the image.

Currently, the former works. My controller code:

```
    public FileResult Index(string imageName)
    {
        var imageUploadPath = _configuration.GetValue<string>("ImageFileLocation");
        var path = string.Concat(imageUploadPath,  "//", imageName);

        return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

I don't have a View for this and would prefer to keep it that way.

I have tried to `return PhysicalFile` but that didn't work for me. Would hard coding the mime type as I have done currently have anything to do with this?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: If you want a user to have the image displayed, plus a "download" button, then you need HTML to enclose both the image and button tags. That means, you need a view. If you simply return the image file only, then the browser treats it differently. (It _might_ display it inline in a browser window, depending on its settings, and then the user can usually right-click to save it permanently. Or it might just download it directly to the hard disk. That bit isn't really under your control as the application developer.)

Comment: Right okay, so there would be no way to simply return a file which appears in the browser (like it currently does for me) and also prompt a 'do you wish to save the file..' pop up? I'd have to create a View and then have a separate download button?

Comment: that's correct. The behaviour is in the control of the browser, not you. If you want to control it, then you have to make your own UI using a view.